# SQL between dates using interval and current_date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to apply a case when to this specific interval, but all attempts leads to a fail.

on my DB table the date is in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

the Table is on Dremio datalake

this are the last attempt I had, tried `interval '3 days'` as well.

```
AND (event_time > current_date - interval 3 day) AND (event_time < current_date - interval 2 day)
```

```
AND event_time BETWEEN TO_CHAR(current_date - 3, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_CHAR(current_date - 2, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: Column event_time data type?

Comment: String (VARCHAR)

Comment: Use a proper date data type instead.

Comment: Thanks I have found a way to do it without changing the data type of table I do not have access to edit.

AND (event_time > CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL '3' DAY) AND (event_time < CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL '2' DAY)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way:

```
AND (event_time > CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL '3' DAY) AND (event_time < CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL '2' DAY)
```